# Displaying limited results per values SQL

Tags: sql

I'm learning SQL on my own. I'm trying to write a query with several values of results per condition.

For example: I have a table with cars. I have cars like OPEL (900 results), AUDI (1000 results) and BMW (1500 results)

I want to use a query something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM carsDB 
WHERE carsID in ('opelID', 'audiID', 'bmwID')
```

and I want display every 400 results for OPEL, 400 results for AUDI and 400 results for BMW.

Can you help me solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `row_number()` -- if you want 1200 rows in the result set:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY carsID ORDER BY carsID) as seqnum
      FROM carsDB c
      WHERE carsID in ('opelID', 'audiID', 'bmwID')
     ) c
WHERE seqnum <= 400;
```

Note:  It seems odd to me that `carsID` is not unique in a table named "cars".  And the "id" values look like brands or manufacturers to me.

Comment: You are awesome, thank you!
But i think I don't understand this:

SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY carsID ORDER BY carsID) as seqnum
      FROM carsDB c
      WHERE carsID in ('opelID', 'audiID', 'bmwID')

Can you tell more or give any URL with explanation?

Comment: @KammiDev . . . Look in the documentation for your database on what `row_number()` does.